# Rowsum several groups of columns with a particular pattern of names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame as follows:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, matrix(round(rnorm(45), 1), 5, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0(rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 2:4), sequence(2:4)))))

#   ID   A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3   C4
# 1  1 -0.6  1.7  1.2  1.8 -1.1 -1.7  0.4  0.7 -0.7
# 2  2 -0.2  0.5  0.4  0.5 -0.2  0.8 -0.3  0.6 -0.2
# 3  3  1.6 -1.3  0.4 -2.0 -1.0  0.2  0.9 -0.1 -1.3
# 4  4  0.1 -0.7  0.1  0.7 -0.7 -1.1  0.9 -0.3  2.2
# 5  5  0.1 -0.4 -0.6 -0.5 -0.6  1.3  0.8 -0.4  1.2
```

I need to row-sum several groups of columns with a particular pattern of names. In this example, I want to create `A_sum`, `B_sum`, and `C_sum` that are calculated by summing up columns starting with `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'` respectively.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(A_sum = rowSums(pick(starts_with('A'))),
         B_sum = rowSums(pick(starts_with('B'))),
         C_sum = rowSums(pick(starts_with('C'))))

#   ID   A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3   C4 A_sum B_sum C_sum
# 1  1 -0.6  1.7  1.2  1.8 -1.1 -1.7  0.4  0.7 -0.7   1.1   1.9  -1.3
# 2  2 -0.2  0.5  0.4  0.5 -0.2  0.8 -0.3  0.6 -0.2   0.3   0.7   0.9
# 3  3  1.6 -1.3  0.4 -2.0 -1.0  0.2  0.9 -0.1 -1.3   0.3  -2.6  -0.3
# 4  4  0.1 -0.7  0.1  0.7 -0.7 -1.1  0.9 -0.3  2.2  -0.6   0.1   1.7
# 5  5  0.1 -0.4 -0.6 -0.5 -0.6  1.3  0.8 -0.4  1.2  -0.3  -1.7   2.9
```

The code above works well but it will repeat the same expression for many times if I have more columns other than `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'`. If I have collected all of the possible prefixes into a vector, i.e.

```r
prefix <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
```

How could I get the expected output with a compact syntax?

---

##### Edit

For a general purpose, I expect that `prefix` is flexible so that if I set `prefix <- c('A', 'C')`, then `B1` to `B3` won't require to be sum up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you have recorded the prefixes of column names that need to be sum up:

```r
prefix <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Then you can use `map()` or `reduce()` from `purrr` to iterate througn them:

1. `map()`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(map_dfc(set_names(prefix, paste0, '_sum'),
                 ~ rowSums(pick(starts_with(.x)))))
```

2. `reduce()`

```r
df %>%
  reduce(.init = ., .x = prefix,
         .f = ~ mutate(.x, '{.y}_sum' := rowSums(pick(starts_with(.y)))))
```

###### Output

```
#   ID   A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3   C4 A_sum B_sum C_sum
# 1  1 -0.6  1.7  1.2  1.8 -1.1 -1.7  0.4  0.7 -0.7   1.1   1.9  -1.3
# 2  2 -0.2  0.5  0.4  0.5 -0.2  0.8 -0.3  0.6 -0.2   0.3   0.7   0.9
# 3  3  1.6 -1.3  0.4 -2.0 -1.0  0.2  0.9 -0.1 -1.3   0.3  -2.6  -0.3
# 4  4  0.1 -0.7  0.1  0.7 -0.7 -1.1  0.9 -0.3  2.2  -0.6   0.1   1.7
# 5  5  0.1 -0.4 -0.6 -0.5 -0.6  1.3  0.8 -0.4  1.2  -0.3  -1.7   2.9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `split.default` and then `rowSums`

```
df %>%
  cbind(
    list2DF(
      lapply(
        split.default(
          .,
          gsub("\\d+", "_sum", names(.))
        ), rowSums
      )
    )
  )
```

which gives

```
    A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3   C4 A_sum B_sum C_sum
1 -0.6  1.7  1.2  1.8 -1.1 -1.7  0.4  0.7 -0.7   1.1   1.9  -1.3
2 -0.2  0.5  0.4  0.5 -0.2  0.8 -0.3  0.6 -0.2   0.3   0.7   0.9
3  1.6 -1.3  0.4 -2.0 -1.0  0.2  0.9 -0.1 -1.3   0.3  -2.6  -0.3
4  0.1 -0.7  0.1  0.7 -0.7 -1.1  0.9 -0.3  2.2  -0.6   0.1   1.7
5  0.1 -0.4 -0.6 -0.5 -0.6  1.3  0.8 -0.4  1.2  -0.3  -1.7   2.9
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the quick reply. Actually there are many other columns in my real data, e.g. `ID`, and I just want to manipulate on those columns whose names starting with a specific set of words. So the column selection process matters in my case.

Comment: @user18894435 In that case I think Darren's solutions can help.